# Reading formatted file containing different types

Tags: c, file, c11

I'm trying to read from a file with the format:

12,6:23.4

I need to collect the 12, 6 and 23.4 separately but I can't seem to get around the comma and colon.

Here is my attempt:

```c
int x = fscanf(fp, "%d %[^,] %d %s %f", &int_var, comma_buffer, &int_var_2, colon_buffer, &float_var);
```

But I get garbage outputs like:

```
int_var_1: 12

Comma_buffer: ��#� 

int_var_2:  0.000000 

colon buffer: , 

float_var: 0.000000
```

Comment: Try `"%d ,%d :%f"`.

Comment: That is far simpler than I expected to be honest. wish my lecturer had pointed this out, thank you

Comment: `int_var_2:  0.000000` occurs because the `,` was never read, scanning stopped and code did not check the return value before printing.

Comment: Yeah apologies, that comma is actually stuff left over from my original code's output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `','` and `':'` in the format such as `"%d,%d:%f"`. Consider a preceding space to tolerate optional white-space before the fixed character: `"%d ,%d :%f"`.

---

The best way to read a *line* from a file is `fgets()`, then parse.

Consider using `" %n"` to detect trailing junk.

```
#define LINE_SZ 100
char buf[LINE_SZ];

if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(buf, "%d ,%d :%f %n", &int_var, &int_var_2, &float_var, &n);
  if (n == 0 || buf[n]) {
    puts("failed to parse all or extra junk.");
  } else {
    printf("%d,%d:%f\n", int_var, int_var_2, float_var);
  }
}
```

---

Both `"%[^,]"` and `"%s"` should **never** be used as they lack a *width*, something robust code always use.